# Autofilter in VBA when criteria is has more words separated by a comma and is in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, filter, multi-select, autofilter

I don't know coding. I want to write the following VBA code for a condition whose Criteria1 is in cell D1 in another sheet. please guide me.
Thank you very much for your effort.
Data sheet is in "**Projects**" sheet and in table= "**projectstbl**" and Data column= **AC** column, Field= **29**, Header=**1st row**, Table Range= **A2:AQ2100**
Criteria is in "**keywords analysis**" sheet, **D1** cell

VBA code:

```
Sub MaterialWise()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const TableName As String = "projectstbl"
    Const CriteriaCellAddress As String = "D1"
    Const Delimiter As String = ", "
    Const CriteriaColumn As Long = 4
    
    ' Reference the worksheet ('ws').
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    ' Reference the table ('tbl').
    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(TableName)
    ' Reference the Criteria cell ('cCell').
    Dim cCell As Range: Set cCell = ws.Range(CriteriaCellAddress)
    
    ' Using the Split function, write the criteria strings
    ' to the Criteria array ('cArr'), a 1D zero-based array.
    Dim cArr() As String: cArr = Split(CStr(cCell.Value), Delimiter)
    
    ' Clear table filters.
    With tbl
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then
            If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End If
    End With
    
    Dim FoundMore As Boolean
    
    ' Handle up to two criteria...
    
    With tbl.Range
        Select Case UBound(cArr)
        Case Is < LBound(cArr) ' blanks
            .AutoFilter CriteriaColumn, ""
        Case 0 ' 1 criterion
            .AutoFilter CriteriaColumn, "*" & cArr(0) & "*"
        Case 1 ' 2 criteria
            .AutoFilter CriteriaColumn, _
                "*" & cArr(0) & "*", xlOr, "*" & cArr(1) & "*"
        Case Else
            FoundMore = True
        End Select
    End With
    
    If Not FoundMore Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Handle more than two criteria...
    
    ' Write the values from the column to the Data array ('Data'),
    ' a 2D one-based one-column array.
    Dim Data() As Variant
    With tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(CriteriaColumn)
        If .Rows.Count = 1 Then ' one cell
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = .Value
        Else ' multiple cells
            Data = .Value
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Create and reference a new dictionary object ('dict').
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' case-insensitive
    
    ' Write the Criteria array's upper limit to a variable ('cUpper')
    ' since it's going to be used in a loop.
    Dim cUpper As Long: cUpper = UBound(cArr)
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim r As Long ' Data Array Row Counter
    Dim c As Long ' Criteria Array Elements Counter
    Dim cString As String ' Current String in Data Array
    
    ' Write the unique strings in the Data array, meeting any of the criteria,
    ' to the 'keys' of the dictionary.
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        cString = CStr(Data(r, 1))
        For c = 0 To cUpper
            If InStr(1, cString, cArr(c), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then Exit For
        Next c
        If c <= cUpper Then dict(cString) = Empty
    Next r
    
    ' Filter the table by the 'keys' of the dictionary.
    tbl.Range.AutoFilter CriteriaColumn, dict.Keys, xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you have makes this task seem complicated, but it's rather simple. Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook:         Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet:    Set wsData = wb.Worksheets("Projects")
    Dim wsKeys As Worksheet:    Set wsKeys = wb.Worksheets("keywords analysis")
    Dim rKeys As Range:         Set rKeys = wsKeys.Range("D1")
    
    'If no data for filter, exit sub, otherwise collect the filter keys into an array
    If Len(rKeys.Value) = 0 Then Exit Sub   'No data
    Dim aKeys As Variant:   aKeys = Split(rKeys.Value, ", ")
    
    'Unfilter the sheet if it's already filtered
    If wsData.AutoFilterMode Then wsData.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    
    'Apply filter using the keys collected
    With wsData.ListObjects("projectstbl").Range
        '4 is the column number to filter (column D if your data starts in column A)
        .AutoFilter 4, aKeys, xlFilterValues
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your help.
The code worked fine. But another sheet that is connected to the data sheet and the formula of its cells has UDF code gives a value error. I have a code that only filters for one word, but not for multiple words (which are separated by commas). Is it possible to add multi-word mode from the previous code to this code?
Many thanks
The code is posted in the next comment:

Comment: @Abdolrasoulshafiey That should be a new question

Comment: `Sub Filtering_AC_v2()
  
  Dim namebakhsh As String
  
  namebakhsh = Worksheets("Keywords Analysis").Range("D1").Value
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  With Worksheets("Projects")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("A1:AQ" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AC").End(xlUp).Row).AutoFilter Field:=29, Criteria1:=namebakhsh
  End With
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub`